# PBXCp error no such file or directory

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, pbxcp

I'm getting this PBXCp error saying there is no such file or directory even though i checked and the file is there. Tried going into targets and Copy Bundle Resources deleted the file in question from there and adding it again did not solve the issue. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Screenshot for error]

Answer (score 5):

PBXCp is a build utility; it copies files.

Your error is caused by it trying to copy a file, and not being able to put the file at the indicated place.

For instance: I'm getting this error as I try to build an extension for an App that is not building; my issue was that PBXCp is trying to install the extension, which did build properly, into an app bundle (essentially, a directory) that doesn't exist, which fails.

Since you're using CocoaPods, check to see whether anything needs updating or reinstalling. You could also be getting this error if you are using multiple schemes, and the results of one build are needed by a later step. If the first build fails, this error will occur in the later build step.

Comment: pod install & clean build did the job

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, just find unnecessary files (they have red title name color)

Comment: also check changes from git (could pulled with wrong changes)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue after I added some extra files in my project by copy pasting them from another. Like suggested by many others, I tried to find the faulty file by checking in Project settings- Building Phases. Dint work. While copying, I also had copied a view controller in my storyboard. I reverted my change and re did it. Worked. May be I made some mistake while changing identifier name or something. Don't know. But if nothing works and u can't figure out what's wrong, undo and redo the copying again step by step. Hope it helps someone.