# PBXCp Error : /.../Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig: No such file or directory

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, cocoapods, pbxcp

I have taken checkout of project and getting error as :

```
PBXCp Error : /.../Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig: No such file or directory
```

Why is this so? Also what does *PBXCp* mean?

This is same [Pods issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31130558/1753005) I'm facing.

[image: Screenshot for error]

Answer (score 1):

Some possible solutions:

1. Try relaunching Xcode.
2. Close Xcode, run `pod install` (If there's an update waiting for CocoaPods, update it); then, open it again. Xcode might have failed to pick up changes while it is open.
3. Check that the xcconfig files are set in your project to the
   CocoaPods generated xcconfig files. Goto `Project`> `Info`> `Configurations`

And remember, always open workspace (.xcworkspace) file.

Comment: This step I had tried before posting question but didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

PBXCp is a build utility; it copies files.

Your error is caused by it trying to copy a file, and not finding the file at the expected location.

I'm getting this error as I try to build an extension for an App that is not building; PBXCp is trying to install the extension, which did build properly, into an app bundle that doesn't exist, which fails.

Since you're using CocoaPods, the advice on reinstalling is good. You could also be getting this error if you have a lot of compile steps that depend on one another; try building your project scheme-by-scheme, once, and that might at least get bundle directories into all the places they're needed.